# How to add VBA label values?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just a beginner in using VBA in MS Excel. I have 1 form and 5 labels. Let's just name it Label1 to Label5. I want to have the sum of values of Label1 to Label4 and display it on Label5.

```
With UserForm1

   Dim str As String
   str = Label5.Caption
   str = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Label1.Caption, .Label2.Caption, _
         .Label3.Caption, .Label4.Caption)
End With
```

This is the code that I got but it doesn't work. Please help T_T

Comment: You can see my answer below.
For what doesn't work in your code : You want Label5 to be Sum of everything, but, right now, it's str that get the sum of the labels captions. `For str = .label5.caption` just give the string inside Label5 caption to the str variable, and doesn't "rename" .Label5.caption to a shorter name

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using `Labels`? wouldn't a `TextBox` be a better approach?

Comment: @Thryn the code you gave worked but when I put the code on another set of labels, it got error saying it's overflow.

Comment: @Zac I just don't need some user input during the program. The values of the labels come from the worksheet cells.

Comment: @KennethArellanoUbaldo You can use Long, alternativly, if you have no floating point with `Clng`. And you can "Lock" Textbox so no user can edit them with the Enable option.

Comment: Okay now I remember what's the cause of that overflow. I remember that when I used `Double` instead of `Integer` and it worked.

Comment: @Thryn thank you very much for the help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because you put the result of `Sum` into `str` but not into `Label5`.

Note that a `String` variable is not an object but just a string value. So it does not reference to `Label5.Caption` instead `str = Label5.Caption` just **copies** the value of `Label5.Caption` into the variable `str` (no referencing).

```
With UserForm1
   .Label5.Caption = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Label1.Caption, .Label2.Caption, .Label3.Caption, .Label4.Caption)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

`.Label5.caption = Cdec(.Label1.Caption) + Cdec(.Label2.Caption) + Cdec(.Label3.Caption) + Cdec(.Label4.Caption)`

Comment: Ah, you're right, I implied that it was integer to begin with. I shouldn't. Let me edit that